# calling source from within a function

Tags: fish, esp-idf

I'm currently moving from zsh to fish. Most of my aliases etc are pretty easy to port, but I'm running into problems with the following one:

```bash
alias idf.py='unalias idf.py; source $IDF_PATH/export.sh; idf.py'
```

I know in fish aliases are just syntactic sugar for functions so I started writing the following function:

```bash
function "idf.py"
  source $IDF_PATH/export.fish
  functions --erase idf.py
  idf.py $argv
end
```

the export.fish script is from the [esp-idf](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/export.fish) and starts complaining about needing to be sourced. After that the function gets removed correctly but idf.py can not be found:

```
his script should be sourced, not executed:
realpath: /home/robert/Programs/esp-idf/export.fish/..: Not a directory
.
fish: Unknown command: idf.py
fish: 
  idf.py $argv
  ^
in function 'idf.py'
```

Do you have any idea how I can source to the global scope from within this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going on the commit history of the project you linked to -- The ESP-IDF script you linked is the latest version, but the error you are receiving was from a bug in an [earlier version](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/a1f5866424597ef5c727bef4d30c2027761e7d1a/export.fish) of the script that has since been fixed.

The script attempts to detect whether it is being called with the `source` command by testing `status current-command`, but since you are calling it from within the function `idf.py`, *that's* the name returned, rather than `source`.

It was a bug, and it was fixed about two years ago by simply removing the source check.

Upgrading to the latest ESP-IDF release should take care of it.